# NetworkX tutorial gives key error over value selection

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, nodes, networkx

I'm working through a networkX tutorial, and page nine is this:

```
>>> g = nx . Graph ()
>>> g . add_node (1 , name = ‘ Obrian ’)
>>> g . add_nodes_from ([2] , name = ‘ Quintana ’ ])
>>> g [1][ ‘ name ’]
‘ Obrian ’
```

Which I reconstructed in code:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph() 

g.add_node(1,name='Obrian')
g.add_nodes_from([2],name='Quintana')

print  "Node 1 name: " + g[1]['name']
```

And yet, for some reason, this simple 5-line script dosn't run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NetTest[nx_tut]--[P09].py", line 9, in <module>
    print  "Node 1 name: " + g[1]['name']
KeyError: 'name'
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious. What is it?

Comment: I think it should be: `g.node[1]['name']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to access the node property of the graph explicitly. That is, replace `g[1]['name']` with `g.node[1]['name']`

You may be working from an out-of-date tutorial.

Comment: Yep, now it's working fine. The tutorial is this one: http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-2012/nx_tutorial.pdf

Comment: Yeah, that tutorial is at least 4 years old. networkx has changed a lot since then. [Here is the latest version of their official tutorial](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/tutorial/index.html)